# What happens when you apply the list() function to a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some trouble understanding the differences between the toarray() and list() functions in python. Consider the following code:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

sentences_word2vec = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'test', 'sentence'],
            [ 'this', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'one', 'in', 'the', 'test'],
            ['we', 'need', 'a', 'second-last', 'test', 'sentence', 'for', 'our', 'test','script'], 
            ['this', 'is', 'the', 'last', 'one', 'now', 'we"re', 'done']]

model = Word2Vec(sentences_word2vec, min_count=1)
print(list(model.wv.vocab))
```

If I run this script I get the following output:

```
['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'test', 'sentence', 'second', 'one', 'in', 'we', 
'need', 'a', 'second-last', 'for', 'our', 'script', 'last', 'now', 'we are', 'done']
```

This is what I want, but I don't really get how the `list()` function works in this case. If I run the script without it, that is, instead run `print(model.wv.vocab)`, I get the following output:

```
{'this': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2828>, 
'is': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2860>, 
'the': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2898>, 
'first': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c28d0>, 
'test': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2908>, 
'sentence': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2940>, 
'second': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2978>, 
'one': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c29b0>,
'in': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c29e8>, 
'we': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2a20>, 
'need': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2a58>, 
'a': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2a90>, 
'second-last': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2ac8>, 
'for': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2b00>, 
'our': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2b38>, 
'script': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2b70>, 
'last': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2ba8>, 
'now': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2be0>, 
'we are': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2c18>, 
'done': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab object at 0x1072c2c50>}
```

**Question:** How does `list()` turn this mysterious dictionary (at least very mysterious to me) into the nice vocabulary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(d)` returns the list of the keys of `d` (also accessible as `d.keys()`). If a dictionary is treated as an iterable (e.g., also in a `for` loop), it generates its keys.